# live stream with zero latency ( ultra low latency UUL) with AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, live-streaming

I want to stream an ongoing live event with zero latency, and after some research, I find some AWS services like:-

1. [on-demand-stream](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/streaming/)
2. [live-stream](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/streaming/)

but I don't find any other better or cost-efficient way to live stream event can you please suggest me any better way to stream my event.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the exact answer you want, but I have released Ultra-low latency streaming server as open source. If you want to use my open source, visit [my GitHub](https://github.com/AirenSoft/OvenMediaEngine/) and use it whenever possible.

I hope my project will help you.

Answer (score 0):

AWS services will have significant latency of several seconds.